# window.width() jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to fire this jquery function if screen size is less than 768, but it is not working.
This is my function and please any one help me to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(widow).width(); 
    alert(width);
    if((width <= 768  ){
        $('body').addClass('js');
        var $menu = $('#menu'),
        $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
        $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');


        $menulink.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $menulink.toggleClass('active');
            $menu.toggleClass('active');
        });

        $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"? *what* isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Major syntax error on line 2

widow should be window

another one on line 4...

if((width <= 768  ){

should be

if(width <= 768  ){

didn't check beyond that, but that would be enough to make the code fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(window).width(); 
    alert(width);
    if(width <= 768  ){
      $('body').addClass('js');
      var $menu = $('#menu'),
      $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
      $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');

     $menulink.on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
     });

     $menuTrigger.on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
     });
}
});
```

Note the typo of `window` the extra opening bracket in your `if` statement and use of `on('click')` rather than `click()`